# HTML5 : Previously displayed image no longer appears

Tags: html, css, nginx

Referring to the index file below, I tried several variations of the image tag  lines of code to make an image appear on my website. None are working. Oddly, the image had been displayed earlier, but is no longer showing up. The only change I can think of that might have caused this is that I took out the body tags. I haven't tried reinserting them. I also have not made any changes to my server configuration recently. Please let me know if you need any more information to help solve this issue. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--Content-->
<html lang = "en">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:100px;">:)</h1>

  <p style="text-align:center;">
    Hi.
  </p>

  <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>

  <img class = "fix">
         <source src = "data/www/pikachu.jpg"/>
  </img>
<!--Menu-->
<nav>
        <ul>
                <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="art.html">Art</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="writing.html">Writing</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
</nav>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, missing body tag is the problem. try to put the content inside the body tag and it will work.

Comment: Ok, images are now showing. Problem solved, thank you